Overlapping splot colourmap with 2-d points Gnuplot
It seams a simple question but I didn't find a solution elsewhere.
I am plotting a colourmap with splot and would like to add to the plot the points at which the space was sampled.
I'll show the code using a 3 dimensional case, but it could be 3-d or higher
Set and unset used:
number_of_variables = 3
set contour base
set palette model RGB
set palette defined ( 0 'white', 1 'dark-red' )
set dgrid3d 31, 31
unset clabel
unset surface
set view map
set pm3d 
set datafile missing NaN

Section where the splot is used:
do for [i=1:number_of_variables-1]{ 
  set xlabel sprintf("b %d", i)
  do for [j=i+1:number_of_variables] {
    set ylabel sprintf("b %d", j)
    set title sprintf("Kriging expected improvement with sampling point %d vs %d", i, j)
    splot "sf1.dat" using i:j:(((column(number_of_variables+1) == (i-1))||(column(number_of_variables+1) == -1)&&((column(number_of_variables+2) == (j-1))||(column(number_of_variables+2) == -1))) ? column(number_of_variables+5) : 1/0) notitle w l lt -1, \
            "sf2.dat" using i:j:(0) w p pt 7 ps 1.5 lc rgb "black" title "Sampled points"
    pause -1 
  }
}

Example data for a 3d case:
"$sf1.dat" has 6 columns: x y z of each point, plotted 2 dimensions at a time, 2 columns used in the rule and 1 column for the value of the colourmap
number of rows are 31^3
-0.150764 -0.0776023 0.00485263 0 1 0.333911
-0.150764 0.066001 0.0012847 0 1 0.343821
etc...

"$sf2.dat" has 3 columns: x y z and I want to plot 2 dimensons at a time
number of rows are around 35
0.77489 0.866638 0.697351 
0.175989 0.00346154 1.01085 
etc... 

The rule for the third column chooses if to pass the last column or 1/0 based on the value of the 4th and 5th column for the case above.
The problem:
splot "sf1.dat" using i:j:rule notitle w l lt -1,\
      "sf2.dat" using i:j:(0) w p pt 7 ps 1.5 lc rgb "black" title "Sampled points"

Where splot is used, I get a white rectangle on the graph (white because I assign value 0) instead of the dots at the sampled locations.
The output I get - image
Image of sf1.dat I want to plot the dots on
If I use a table and plot both in 2D I get the dots at the correct location, and instead of the colourmap it shows the contour lines (I would like the opposite).
Full data: sf1.dat sf2.dat
If I missed anything please add a comment.
Thank you for the help
Edit 1
I am using Gnuplot verion 5.4 patchlevel 2, last modified 01-06-2021.

Which version of gnuplot are you using? Could you please change your script to a minimal and complete example to actually reproduce your output? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@theozh Thanks for the reply, I have added the relevant part of the code so it runs, sorry about that.
I have uploaded the full data to google drive and the link is on the question.

thanks for the update and the data. However, I yet still don't understand how you want sf1.dat to be plotted. As lines? As a map? As interpolated map? As filtered (by rule) map?

@theozh Sorry I was going on a new line and I sent it.
The rule just takes a slice out of a multidimensional data.
sf1.dat should be plotted as a colourmap which it does when using the first line of splot (added an image in the question)
splot "sf1.dat" using i:j:rule notitle w l lt -1
The problem is in plotting the points in sf2.dat on top (in the first iteration I would like a dot on every x, y in sf2.dat - first 2 columns)

I'm not 100% sure whether the following is the way you want it to look like.
My first thought would be to plot the data via dgrid3d into a table and then plot it as 2D-plot and overlaying the other points. This should work for gnuplot>=5.0. I read somehwere that gnuplot>=5.4.3 might have some options to do it without plotting to a table first, but since you have 5.4.2...

You can also play with qnorm <value>, check help dgrid3d.
Script: (works for gnuplot>=5.4.0, apparently needs some adaptions for <5.4.0)
### point data on top of dgrid3d data
reset session

FILE1 = "SO79089934_sf1.dat"
FILE2 = "SO79089934_sf2.dat"

N       = 3    # number_of_variables
rule(n) = ((column(n+1) == (i-1))||(n+1) == -1) && \
          ((column(n+2) == (j-1))||(column(n+2) == -1)) ? column(n+5) : 1/0

set palette defined ( 0 'white', 1 'dark-red' )
set size ratio -1
set xrange noextend
set yrange noextend
set key noautotitle
unset contour
set dgrid3d 31,31 qnorm 1

do for [i=1:N-1]{ 
    do for [j=i+1:N] {
        set xlabel sprintf("b %d", i)
        set ylabel sprintf("b %d", j)
        set table $GridFile1
            splot FILE1 u 1:2:(rule(N))
        unset table
        set title sprintf("Kriging expected improvement with sampling point %d vs %d", i, j)

        plot $GridFile1 u 1:2:3 w image lc palette z, \
                  FILE2 u i:j w p pt 7 ps 1.5 lc rgb "black" ti "Sampled points"
        if (i*j < N*(N-1)) { pause -1 }
    }
}
### end of script

Result:


This one gives a warning: 
Warning: empty x range [1.42008:1.42008], adjusting to [1.40588:1.43428]


Thank you for your patience, it is exactly what I needed. I am still learning to program decently and it is always nice to be reminded how a nice code looks.
I was unsetting the surface in another part of the code which was not showing the contour. Now it works.
